# Show that $(f_{n}g_{n})$ converges to $fg$ in $L^{1}(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f,g,f_{n},g_{n}$, $ n\geq 1$ be measurable functions on X such that:

(i) $(f_{n})$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}(\mu)$.

(ii) $|g_{n}| \leq 2$ for all $n$ and $(g_{n})$ converges to $g$ $\mu-a.e.$

Show that $(f_{n}g_{n})$ converges to $fg$ in $L^{1}(\mu)$.

So what we want is that $\lim_{n} \int |f_{n}g_{n} - fg | d\mu = 0$ .

The condition $(ii)$ makes me think of Dominated Convergence Theorem, but we don't know if $\int 2 d\mu$ is integrable so it can't be used directly.

Since $f_{n}$ converges in mean it does also converge in measure. Can we do something like:

Define $\mathcal{N}_{f} := \{ x \in X: \lim_{n} |f_{n} - f| > \epsilon \}$, $\epsilon > 0$, and similary $ \mathcal{N}_{g} := \{x \in : \lim_{n} g_{n}(x) \neq g(x) \} $.

If $x \in (\mathcal{N}_{f} \cup \mathcal{N}_{g})^{c}$, can we then deduce that $\lim_{n,m} f_{n}g_{m}(x) = \lim_{n} f_{n}g(x) = fg(x)$? Since $g$ is bounded we will never take $f_{n}(\infty)$ or something undefined.

Can we then do something like:

$\lim_{n,m} \int |f_{n}g_{m} - fg| d\mu = \lim_{n} \int |g(f_{n} - f)| d\mu \leq \lim_{n} \int 2 | f_{n} - f | d\mu = 0$

and how about the Null-sets which union has a measure of zero, $\mu( \mathcal{N}_{f} \cup \mathcal{N}_{g}) \leq \mu(\mathcal{N}_{f}) + \mu(\mathcal{N}_{g}) = 0 + 0$?

This might be completely wrong and stupid, but I would appreciate comments about my thoughts, where I go wrong and why it is wrong. A solution is of course also appreciated!

/ Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do this, since you also asked for a possibly different solution.

First, write
$$
f_ng_n-fg=(f_n-f)g_n+f(g_n-g)=h_n+k_n.
$$
Since each $|g_n|$ is bounded by $2$, the pointwise limit $g$ is bounded by $2$ a.e. Therefore 
$$
\int|h_n|\leq2\int|f_n-f|\longrightarrow 0. 
$$

Now the sequence $|k_n|$ is dominated by $|f|(|g_n|+|g|)\leq 4|f|$ a.e. This yields an integrable upper bound independent of $n$. So Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem yields
$$
\lim\int|k_n|=\int\lim|k_n|=0.
$$

Putting these together shows that $f_ng_n$ and $fg$ are integrable (since they are bounded by $2|f_n|$ and $2|f|$ a.e. respectively) and
$$
\int|f_ng_n-fg|\leq \int|k_n|+\int|h_n|\longrightarrow 0.
$$
That is $f_ng_n$ converges to $fg$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! What do you think about my try? I am preparing for an exam on Friday so it is interesting for me to know where I go wrong and make mistakes.

Comment: @Erik Your argument makes it pretty complicated. First, you should use $\limsup$ to make things better. And then consider the union of $N_f$ over $\epsilon>0$, which is still a measure $0$ set. And you should make it clear how you use DCT to take the limit as $m$ tends to infinity. I recommend you go like I did, since you use DCT anyway.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your comments. :)